# Read a file and save to a list

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a file of the form:

```
3
1 2 3 4 5
4 5 6
1 6 2 4 6 7
```

The first line identifies the lines that will follow. Those lines in turn are just a series of numbers. I need to save this into a list that might look like this:

```
N = 3,
Teams = [line(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), line(4, 5, 6), line(1, 6, 2, 4, 6, 7)].
```

What I am trying until now is:

```
read_file(File, N, Lines) :-
    open(File, read, Stream),
    read_line_to_codes(Stream, Line),
    atom_codes(Atom, Line),
    atom_number(Atom, N),
    read_lines(Stream, N, Lines).

read_lines(Stream, N, Lines) :-
    ( N == 0 -> Lines = []
    ; N > 0  -> read_line(Stream, N, Line),
                Nm1 is N-1,
                read_lines(Stream, Nm1, RestLines),
                Lines = [Line | RestLines]).

read_line(Stream, N, line()) :-
    read_line_to_codes(Stream, Line),
    atom_codes(Atom, Line),
    atomic_list_concat([N | Atoms], ' ', Atom),
    maplist(atom_number, Atoms, []).
```

But there seems to be an issue with `atomic_list_concat([N | Atoms], ' ', Atom),` I think. This is my first touch with prolog so I am not sure what is going on. How can I fix the code above?

Comment: `Atoms` is unbound, but the documentation shows that it must be bound (that's what the + means in `atomic_list_concat(+List, +Separator, -Atom)`. But in general I would solve this problem a totally different way, using DCGs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely approach this with [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)s. The idea here is to make a simple grammar for your input and use that to parse the file.

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

input(N, Teams) --> integer(N), blanks, teams(Teams).
teams([Team|Teams]) --> team(Team), blank, teams(Teams).
teams([]) --> [].

team([X|Xs]) --> integer(X), whites, team(Xs).
team([]) --> [].
```

The library `dcg/basics` is providing us with four utility functions we're using here: `blank`, `blanks`, `whites` and `integer/1`. These parse a blank space including newlines, multiple blank spaces including newlines, and multiple whitespace charaters *not* including newlines, and integers.

The grammar says an input consists of an integer N, a blank line and then some teams. The teams are either a team, a blank, and some more teams, or we're done. The same idea is deployed to get a team: we either have an integer and some spaces and some more integers, or we are done. Note how much shorter and more declarative the DCG version is than the byte-mangling approach!

Using it is fairly easy too:

```
?- phrase_from_file(input(N, Teams), 'input.txt').
N = 3,
Teams = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [1, 6, 2, 4, 6, 7]] ;
false.
```

You could hoist that into a utility predicate if you want:

```
parse(Filename, N, Teams) :- phrase_from_file(input(N, Teams), Filename).

?- parse('input.txt', N, Teams).
N = 3,
Teams = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [1, 6, 2, 4, 6, 7]] .
```

Enjoy!

**Edit**: I would probably not change this to return `line(1,2,3,4,5), line(4,5,6), ...`, because you will find it unpleasant to handle variable arity structures. But if you really want to, you could replace the `team//1` rule with this instead:

```
team(Team) --> team_list(TeamList), { Team =.. [list|TeamList] }.
team_list([X|Xs]) --> integer(X), whites, team_list(Xs).
team_list([]) --> [].
```

Here we're using univ (`=..`) to build a term out of the list. Again, I wouldn't deploy this idea here because your processing will get more complex for probably no real gain.